# How to cache github repos so 2nd git clone will use the cache instead of github repo

Tags: git, caching, github

senario:

1) we're in China, so access github is slow and sometimes impossible, and as u know, we can't live w/out github.

2) when developing iOS projects, we use Cocoapods, and it uses a lot github repos, so when installing pods, many command like `git clone git@github.com/reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa` will be triggered.

so is there any way can we improve this process? the best solution to me seems to make a local cache of these github repos, when triggering `git clone git@github.com/reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa` it's actually triggering `git clone http://192.168.1.199/repos/reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa`, and the server can tell if certain pod exists, if yes return the cached, else make a github request and cache the result.

but can't find a workable strategy to achieve this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa".insteadOf "http://192.168.1.199/repos/reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa"
```

Comment: it works! some tips: the cloned repos in 192.168.1.199 should append `--bare`, maybe need `git update-server-info`

Comment: `git config --global url."http://192.168.1.199/repos/reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa".insteadOf "git@github.com:reactivecocoa/ReactiveCocoa"`

Comment: to make it even easier, i made a script to do this https://github.com/lzyy/github-proxy